VS Code doesn't set current opened folder as cwd
Here's my project settings (\.vscode\settings.json) in VS Code 1.96.2, running on Windows 11 Pro:
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "MINGW64": {
        "path": "C:/msys64/usr/bin/bash.exe",
        "args": [
            "--login",
            "-i"
        ],
        "env": {
            "MSYSTEM": "MINGW64"
        }
    }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "MINGW64",
"terminal.integrated.cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"

Problem: if I open the project folder c:\repos\misc\myproject on VSCode and I do echo $PWD, it prints /home/myuser instead of /c/repos/misc/myproject. Why? How can I set the current folder.
Also, when opening the terminal, it always points to myuser@MYPC MINGW64 ~ instead of myuser@MYPC MINGW64 /c/repos/misc/myproject.
Doing "terminal.integrated.cwd": "c:/repos/misc/myproject" do nothing.
How can I fix?
